# List in order of size

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list that prints out the highest number first with a name next to it, like a football table. This is a set of test code that I have been trying it with.

```
import numpy as np

aa = 5
ab = 3
ac = 8
ad = 6

bb = (aa, ab, ac, ad)

cc = sorted(bb, reverse=True)
splits = np.array_split(cc, 4)

for array in splits:
    print(list(array))
```

It returns the numbers in a descending pattern like this:

```
[8]
[6]
[5]
[3]
```

What I am after looks like:

```
AC - 8
AD - 6
AA - 5
AB - 3
```

Comment: Use a dictionary or list of tuples.

Comment: I'd recommend using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) for this.

Comment: you propably want to store them numbers in a dictionary with `aa`, `ab` as keys. then you can easily sort them by values and print out the key value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for somethings such as this:

```
# You can store elements as list of dictionaries
bb = [{'aa':5},{'ab':3},{'ac':8},{'ad':6}]

# Sorting by value, since key (of each dictionary varies)
cc = sorted(bb, key = lambda x: list(x.values())[0], reverse=True)

# Printing the results
for pair in cc:
    for key, value in pair.items():
        print(key, value)
```

or similarly using a dictionary:

```
bb = {'aa': 5, 'ab': 3, 'ac': 8, 'ad': 6}
cc = sorted(bb.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)

for pair in cc:
    print(pair[0],pair[1])
```

Free to comment below, I will clarify any points of confusion!

Comment: A single dictionary would be simpler than a list of dictionaries: `{'aa': 5, 'ab': 3, 'ac': 8, 'ad': 6}`.